# Creating Tile Service in ArcGIS Online Python API

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-python-api, arcgis-online-webmap

I'm trying to create a tile layer via the [ArcGIS API for Python](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/). When creating a tile layer in AGOL (manually) they have you specify a range of scales for the zoom level (e.g. 1:1000 or 1:4000).

But for the [create_tile_service](https://esri.github.io/arcgis-python-api/apidoc/html/arcgis.gis.toc.html?highlight=tile#arcgis.gis.Item.create_tile_service) method, they tell you to specify the scales as a floating point number. So would the range of **1:1000** and **1:4000** look like this? Otherwise, I'm not sure what scale I should be referring to.

```
gis = GIS('arcgis.com','username','pwd')
some_feature_layer = feature_layer.url
some_feature_layer.create_tile_service('name',
                                        1000.00, # min scale
                                        4000.00) # max scale
```

Comment: If you have "bonus questions" then please ask them as new questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, 1000.0000 is how you would specify a 1:1000 scale when creating a cached tile service. I use 1:1155581.108577 as my greatest scale and the parameter I pass is 1155581.108577.

Also, a tiled service is a REST service endpoint for a tiled layer. So they are not the same thing but when you make a request to a tiled service, you receive a tiled layer (or data from a tiled layer).